# Is my method to detect overfitting in matrix factorization correct?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, matrix-factorization

I am using matrix factorization as a recommender system algorithm based on the user click behavior records. I try two matrix factorization method:

The first one is the basic SVD whose prediction is just the product of user factor vector *u* and item factor *i*: r = *u* * *i*

The second one I used is the SVD with bias component.

r = *u* * *i* + *b_u* + *b_i*

where *b_u* and *b_i* represents the bias of preference of users and items.

One of the models I use has a very low performance, and the other one is reasonable. I really do not understand why the latter one performs worse, and I doubt that it is overfitting.

I googled methods to detect overfitting, and found the learning curve is a good way. However, the x-axis is the size of the training set and y-axis is the accuracy. This make me quite confused. How can I change the size of the training set? Pick out some of the records out of the data set?

Another problem is, I tried to plot the iteration-loss curve (The loss is the ). And it seems the curve is normal:

[image]

But I am not sure whether this method is correct because the metrics I use are precision and recall. Shall I plot the iteration-precision curve??? Or this one already tells that my model is correct?

Can anybody please tell me whether I am going in the right direction? Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in reverse:

So you are trying two different models, one that uses straight matrix factorization r = u * i and the other which enters the biases, r = u * i + b_u + b_i.

You mentioned you are doing Matrix Factorization for a recommender system which looks at user's clicks. So my question here is: Is this an Implicit ratings case? or Explicit one? I believe is an Implicit ratings problem if it is about clicks.

This is the first important thing you need to be very aware of, whether your problem is about Explicit or Implicit ratings. Because there are some differences about the way they are used and implemented.

If you check here: 
http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf

Implicit ratings are treated in a way that the number of times someone clicked  or bought a given item for example is used to infer a confidence level. If you check the error function you can see that the confidence levels are used almost as a weight factor. So the whole idea is that in this scenario the biases have no meaning.

In the case of Explicit Ratings, where one has ratings as a score for example from 1-5, one can calculate those biases for users and products (averages of these bounded scores) and introduce them in the ratings formula. They make sense int his scenario.

The whole point is, depending whether you are in one scenario or the other you can use the biases or not.

On the other hand, your question is about over fitting, for that you can plot training errors with test errors, depending on the size of your data you can have a holdout test data, if the errors differ a lot then you are over fitting.

Another thing is that matrix factorization models usually include regularization terms, see the article posted here, to avoid over fitting.

So I think in your case you are having a different problem the one I mentioned before.